# numeric attribute in which ~48% of the values are missing

Tags: pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have a numeric attribute in which **~48%** of the values are missing.
Tell me, please, is it better to remove a feature with so many emissions from the data frame?
Do I understand correctly that the number of NaN close to half should not be restored?

*< 1 month since I started studying working with data*

Comment: hi, this is a broad and difficult question to answer. Whether or not to remove the feature depends on what you would try to use it for. You could always try both keeping and removing the feature and compare the results. If you have a more specific question in the future please don't hesitate to start a new question

Comment: Your question appears to be more concerned with theoretical aspects of data analysis/modeling than with programming. Please ask these kinds of questions on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) or [Data Science SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com).